# Web UI not generating JS bundle file

Tags: zenbot

Running the latest version the web ui pulls up and I can see the image assets but the app.bundle.js returns a 404. Do I need to do anything to build that file or something?

```
Cannot GET /assets-wp/app.bundle.js
```

Answer (score 0):

As per this [issue](https://github.com/DeviaVir/zenbot/issues/1142), make sure you're not running it as `root`, then try reinstalling it via:

```
npm install --unsafe-perm
```